# google app engine urlfetch gzip to string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gzip

Using Google App Engine, I am trying to urlfetch a gzip file from a URL which contains one csv file.

Ultimately I would like to output the content of the csv file on my webpage.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    url = *this_is_my_url*
    test = urlfetch.fetch(url, deadline=25)
    self.response.out.write(test.content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/test', Test)
], debug=True)
```

Rather than printing the contents of the file to screen, it asks me to download them locally.  How do I stop this local download and instead print directly to the screen/webpage?

Comment: looks like a misconfigured browser to me, try with other browsers.

Comment: You might want to try adding a `Content-disposition: inline` header, although in theory it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I have tried with Firefox, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer and each download the file rather than printing it to screen.

Comment: I changed one line to this:
    test = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'Content-disposition': 'inline'}, deadline=25)

It now prints to the screen, but it is gobbledegook... when the file is downloaded the contents are fine but when printed they are something like this:

o�@���+?� ����%UU)q[�

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies and comments by the way!

I forgot to mention I also had to edit out the content-type line to get the reponse to write to the screen.

Comment: What is the strange response I am getting now?  How do I decode this?  As you can guess I am knew to all this so be gentle!

Comment: If "this is my URL" is the URL for a gzipped file, of course it's not going to display as plain text in a web browser; you'll need to un-gzip it first.

Comment: "this is my URL" is a real URL, I've just removed it for displaying on StackOverflow.  How do I un-gzip something?  I thought GAE did this?  When the file is downloaded it comes unzipped...

Comment: You probably need to put the data into a StringIO and then use `gzip.open` to read it.

Comment: OK, I've no idea how to do that so I will have to go digging some more.  Thanks for all your help Wooble!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import gzip
import StringIO

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    url = *this_is_my_url*

    test = urlfetch.fetch(url, deadline=25)


    f = StringIO.StringIO(test.content)
    c = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
    content = c.read()

    self.response.out.write(content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  (r'/', Test)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: You're a superstar Jan!  This worked perfectly.  Thank-you very much.